# Which time series database to use for consistent dev prod (aws) parity

Tags: amazon-web-services, time-series

I deploy my app to AWS.
On AWS there are RDS which support some industrial standard DBMS like PostgreSQL/MySQL/Oracle.
These dbms can be make available on development machine (docker) as well, make it easy to achieve dev/prod parity.

I'm looking for a time series specialized database that I can achieve dev/prod as well.
AWS has Timestream that is specialized for time series, but I'm clueless of a local equivalent database for it.

There probably some EC2-hosted database possible, but I prefer to be lazy and have Amazon take care of manage the database cluster for me.

What options do I have?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same challenge! Very disappointing that Amazon is not offering a mini timestream db docker image!

Answer (score 1):

**Apache Druid** is a very good ***Time-Series Database*** that can be deployed on local development environments and on multiple cloud environments easily.

**Druid** is ofered as a fully managed cloud service, on AWS, by Imply.
The fully managed variant of Druid is called ***Imply Cloud***.

**More information:**  https://imply.io/product/imply-cloud

Comment: Trying Druid atm. Have pinged imply.io for their service. Funny that you have to wait a few days until they show you what their service looks like.

Comment: imply are not responding. I don't think this is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Amazon Timestream](https://aws.amazon.com/timestream/)

It is as a nonrelational, fully managed service built specifically to collect, store and process time-series data. The arrival of masses of IoT data is expected to push time-series technology into wider use,that's why Amazon came with Timestream.

Comment: how can I run Timestream on my local development machine?